# Bash script – "/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

I'm using [this tutorial](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php) to learn bash scripts to automate a few
tasks for me.
I'm connecting to a server using putty.

The script, located in `.../Documents/LOG`, is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
echo "Hello World!"
```

And I executed the following for `read/write/execute permissions`

```
chmod 755 my_script
```

Then, when I enter `./my_script`, I'm getting the error given in the
title.

Some similar questions wanted to see these, so I think they might
help :

```
$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

and

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin/mh
```

I tried adding the current directory to `PATH`, but that doesn't
work …

Comment: How did you create the file? E.g. Which editor / OS

Comment: I created the file in Windows using Notepad++, copied the file over to the server using WinSCP. And I know this isn't the ideal way to do things

Comment: See my answer, this is most likely the issue

Comment: I got this with a hashbang misspelling: ``#! /user/bin/env python``. note ``user`` instead of ``usr``, so check your ``env`` top-line statement

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because the title contained `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, which led me from a Google search directly to a solution. The "duplicate" question did not.

Comment: FYI - I had this problem when duplicating a `.bat` file and changed the extension to `.sh`. My plan was to rewrite the batch code to shell. Creating a new `.sh` file and pasting my code over did the trick.

Comment: I had this problem when working with WSL2 and running Docker backend at the same time. Shutting down Docker and doing `wsl --shutdown`, then starting it again fixed the issue.

Answer (score 852, accepted):

I have seen this issue when creating scripts in Windows env and then porting over to run on a Unix environment.

Try running `dos2unix`  on the script:

http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/

Or just rewrite the script in your Unix env using `vi` and test.

Unix uses different line endings so can't read the file you created on Windows. Hence it is seeing ^M as an illegal character.

If you want to write a file on Windows and then port over, make sure your editor is set to create files in UNIX format.

In notepad++ in the bottom right of the screen, it tells you the document format. By default, it will say `Dos\Windows`. To change it go to

- settings->preferences
- new document / default directory tab
- select the format as unix and close
- create a new document

Comment: You can also just right click on the Dos\Windows text in the bottom right and change it to unix there.

Comment: +1 for such an unlikely solution!! I am using UltraEdit. To achieve the same there, select File -> Conversions -> DOS to Unix

Comment: I open the script in notepad and paste into putty shell , then save it.  Everything fine for now. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I faced same issue. I had written the script in windows env and copied onto linux machine. The error gone after rewriting the script in linux machine itself

Comment: If you use Sublime Text 3 editor, you can convert line endings from Windows to Linux format by selecting
`View->Line Endings->Unix`
and then save your script with
`Ctrl+S`

Comment: Very simply, just use gedit and do a `Save As...` and change the line endings to `Unix/Linux`.

Comment: Changing the settings in Notepad++ is **so much** easier than relearning vi after so many years! :-)

Comment: Or you can also type the following command in your file in VIM : set ff=unix

Comment: Under VSCode you can change the Linefeed option on the bottom right from CRLF to LF to achieve the same as in this post.

Comment: So I have a zip file I created on a mac.  I had downloaded and rezipped it on a windows machine.  (dont ask).  Then I unzipped to a ubuntu machine...and got the error.  But this answer got me on the right track.

Comment: Depending on how git's line ending management is configured this can become an automatically created problem on every script in a project.

Comment: If you consistently have issues like this then [you can symlink /path/to/interpreter^M to /path/to/interpreter](https://natanyellin.com/posts/shebang-python-bad-interpreter-m/) to avoid constantly converting line endings. It's ugly but it works.

Comment: I got `dos2unix: Failed to open temporary output file: Permission denied; dos2unix: problems converting file /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm`

Answer (score 1271):

The reason might be that you saved the file on Windows, with `CR` `LF` as the line ending (`\r\n`).

Run the following command in your terminal:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r$//' scriptname.sh
```

(Of course, change `scriptname.sh` to your file name)

The command will replace those `CR` characters with nothing, which will leave these lines with `LF` (`\n`) as the ending, and Bash will be able to read and execute the file by running

```
./scriptname.sh
```

Comment: If this not worked, try `sed -i -e 's/^M$//' scriptname.sh`. (Press Ctrl+V Ctrl+M to insert that `^M`.)

Comment: This didn't work for  me, including the . However, the original answer  had a solution that did work for me: open the file in Vim and run the following command before saving: :set fileformat=unix listed under the SO question called Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings? did work for me.

Comment: bonus for working on docker containers that don't have dos2unix installed. Though I couldn't overwrite the script in my case so mine looked like `cat scriptname.sh | sed -e 's/\r$//' > fixedscriptname.sh`

Comment: If it helps, I used
    sed -i -e 's/\r$//' *.sh    
which converted all my sh files to make them work

Comment: None of the answers here worked except @Jazzmine `:set fileformat=unix` in `vi`. I have the feeling Linux/Nano was actually changing my file's LF into CRLF for some reason.

Comment: @Robert Molina, windows adds a carriage return character in addition to \n at the end of lines. This command simply removes it by substituting \r for an empty string using the linux stream edit command (sed).

Comment: WHAT this answer explain is that you are not using UNIX end lines. Check accepted answer. If you are working in Windows, for e.g. Notepad++, check for Edit / Convert End Lines / Unix format.

Comment: Works within debian linux.

Comment: This issue occurred for me using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) where it is easy to accidently modify the shell script from Windows and introduce CRLF line endings. An alternative to using `sed` is open VS Code from WSL and in the bottom part of the editor change CRLF to LF and save the file.

Answer (score 166):

If you use **Sublime Text** on Windows or Mac to edit your scripts:

Click on `View > Line Endings > Unix` and **save** the file again.

[image]

Comment: It worked. But can I know the reason which required to perform this action.

Comment: can we make this default behaviour? That is to say, any file edited and saved in Sublime accomplishes this automatically.

Answer (score 79):

In notepad++ you can set it for the file specifically by pressing

Edit --> EOL Conversion --> UNIX/OSX Format

[image]

Comment: That worked.. Thanks

Comment: this is it! thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Saved my time and energy.

Comment: Worked for me for docker init script too

Answer (score 61):

This is caused by editing file in windows and importing and executing in unix.

`dos2unix -k -o filename` should do the trick.

Comment: sorry, it didn't work for me.

Comment: `-k`: Keep the date stamp of output file same as input file. `-o`: Old file mode. Convert file FILE and overwrite output to it. The program defaults to run in this mode.

Answer (score 21):

problem is with dos line ending. Following will convert it for unix

```
dos2unix file_name
```

NB: you may need to install dos2unix first with `yum install dos2unix`

another way to do it is using `sed` command to search and replace the dos line ending characters to unix format:

```
$sed -i -e 's/\r$//' your_script.sh
```

Answer (score 20):

Your file has Windows line endings, which is confusing Linux.

Remove the spurious CR characters. You can do it with the following command:

```
 $ sed -i -e 's/\r$//' setup.sh
```

Comment: This is the magic I need when I can't get scripts to run on windows filesystem..

Answer (score 10):

I was able to resolve the issue by opening the script in [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) and saving it with the proper `Line Ending` option:

> File > Save As...

In the bottom left of the `Save As` prompt, there are drop-down menus for Character Encoding and Line Ending. Change the Line Ending from `Windows` to `Unix/Linux` then Save.

[image: Selecting the "Line Ending" option as "Linux/Unix" in the gedit "Save As" prompt]

Comment: Worked for me using `Mousepad > Document>Line Ending>Unix (LF); Save`.

Answer (score 9):

For [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) users, you can either change the file encoding directly from the menu `File > Convert Line Delimiters To > Unix (LF, \n, 0Α, ¶)`:

[image: Eclipse change file encoding]

Or change the `New text file line delimiter` to `Other: Unix` on `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace` panel:

[image: Eclipse workspace settings]

Comment: _File > Convert Line Delimiters To_ does it but _Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Unix_ does not seem to help.

Comment: @PanuHaaramo that setting is for all **NEW** created files. If you have a file that it's created already, then you have to convert it as in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Atom has a built-in line ending selector package

More details here: https://github.com/atom/line-ending-selector

Answer (score 0):

I develop on Windows and Mac/Linux at the same time and I avoid this ^M-error by simply running my scripts as I do in Windows:

`$ php ./my_script`

No need to change line endings.