# my_script throwing an error of bash: /home/usr/bin/my_sript: bin/bash/ bad interpreter: No such file or directory. How can I correct this error?

Tags: linux, bash

First and foremost the script is a 'hello world' script and it's stored in ~/jared/bin. Here's the script:

```
#!bin/bash
echo "hello world"
```

Based on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-my-script-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory), I tried:

The file is executable? I used:

```
chmod 755 my_script
```

I ran the following commands, and here is the output:

```
which bash
```

> /bin/bash

and finally,

```
echo $PATH
```

> /home/jared/bin:/home/jared/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin

The file endings are UNIX as I wrote the script in VIM. However to be safe, I wrote additional 'hello world' scripts in Sublime and Atom and received the same error when I ran them.

I even tried running [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) on the file.

The script will execute when ran directly from the directory and will execute in any directory if I type `bash hello_world`
However it throws the error if I use `./`

I don't know if this will help, but it seems relevant: I can use tab autocomplete on the script if I don't preface it with `bash` or `./`

I fear, I'm making a really stupid mistake here, hopefully someone is prepared to make me feel incredibly silly today. Thanks!

Comment: + on this question, because you tried much things to solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your script should be

```
#!/bin/bash
  ^
```

It needs to be `#!` followed by an absolute path to bash. Note the slash before `/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

first line should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

you forgot the '/' after '!' so the system cannot find correct (absolute) path to bash