# cqlsh unable to find the version of Python it needs to execute

Tags: python, linux, cassandra, cqlsh, scylla

When I type in: `cqlsh` in my terminal window, I get an error that says:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/cqlsh: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

However, if I type `Python --version` the terminal verifies that  Python 2.7.10 installed on my computer.

It seems to me like `cqlsh` is trying to run python but it is in the wrong directory?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Some more context: I have a docker container with a scylla (cassandra look-alike) database, but I want to use cqlsh locally.

Comment: how did you install cqlsh?

Comment: Is Python installed under `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`?. Also what you can try is to run `dos2unix` on your cqlsh script. Here's a similar problem with bash scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-my-script-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run cqlsh the simplest is to do: sudo docker exec -it some-scylla10 cqlsh

Python2.7 is under /usr/bin/python2.7  inside the scylla container