# /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am facing 
 /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
issue and I have already got the solution for it from this stack flow answer

[-bash: ./my_script: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-my-script-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

which works fine.

My question is every time when I restart my ubuntu machine I have to redo everything 
That is I execute 
dos2unix -k -o filename
every time I start my system.

Is there any way this can be just once?

*Please note: I had to create a new question because I was not able to ask the question or comment in the existing question due to less reputation*

Comment: Maybe you are running a virtual machine that doesn't save changes to disk?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this more than once, which would seem to indicate that the file is being re-written. Is it being copied from a remote or something?

Comment: It is not normal for the line endings on a file to change after a reboot, so there must be something unusual in your environment. Can you expand a little bit more on your setup? Is the script on a network share, or are you using a VM with a shared directory with a host OS? Is the script being edited by something in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

The first line of your bash script should be the Shebang (**#!/bin/bash**).

I see the error says: */bin/bash*
But is should be changed to: *#!/bin/bash*

Then run:

```
$ dos2unix my_script
```

This will change all the line terminators from **\r\n** (Windows) to **\n** (Linux), this will modify the original **my_script** file so it will persist even after a reboot.

Comment: The OP already mentioned that he runs `dos2unix` to fix the executable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem of running a bash script from a file saved with Microsoft OS machine (a virtual machine maybe?) such as Windows or DOS.

So you know the fix to your problem.

Now you should prevent your problem reoccurring every time you login. Identify how the file is generated/copied/damaged by another resource. Like `.bash_profile` script or `crontab` script or any other management deamon.

Comment: You can also just [symlink #!/bin/bash^M to #!/bin/bash](https://natanyellin.com/posts/shebang-python-bad-interpreter-m/).