# Bash Script cd command truncates directory name

Tags: linux, windows, bash

I'm learning bash and I tried to make a simple script that changes the directory and executes a command, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd adf-elite-connector
<execute a command>
```

But I was getting the following error:

> -bash: ./dc.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

If I removed the bin/bash header and have the following script:

```
cd adf-elite-connector
<execute a command>
```

I would get an error with a truncated directory name:

> : No such file or directoryite-connector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-bash: ./my\_script: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14219092/608639)

Answer (score 0):

I was creating the script in windows and I was uploading the file to linux. End Of Line characters (EOL) differ between windows and linux. So all I had to do is convert EOL characters from windows to linux.

This can be done with Notepad++, going to Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF)

After I uploaded the converted file, it would change the directory and execute the command without a problem.