# VS Code, how to set up for writing for linux machine

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio

I have been working with a script, which I haven't done for some time now. It was suggested to me to use VS code to develop the script and then I use pscp to get the file from my windows computer into the Linux machine which I am connected to.

Once I do this and attempt to run the script on the Linux machine I get the following error:
`/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

In my  `settings.json` file of VS Code I have my terminal.intergrated.shell.windows set to a bash.exe. I have came across this question:
 [Bash script and /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-script-and-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

and from it one of the suggestions was because I am importing from a windows to linux machine there are some characters which do not cross over correctly thus the ^M error. Is there a way to set up VS Code to code in a Linux environment when it is transferred over? 
Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 3):

at the bottom of VSCode there should be a little toolbar.
If you click on `CRLF` and instead change it to `LF` your problems should be resolved when developing the code from then onwards. The reason this happens is because whenever you create a new line in Windows it takes two characters to do so. The `CR` (Carriage Return) and `LF` (Line Feed) whereas Linux only uses `LF` (Line Feed).

Hope this helped :)

[image: LF CRLF]

Comment: This also works in Visual Studio (2022)