# How do you write lifecycle configurations for SageMaker on windows?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to set up a startup lifecycle configuration for a SageMaker sketchbook (which just ends up being a .sh file), and it seems like, regardless of what I do, my notebooks timeout on startup. I simplified everything as much as possible, to the point of commenting out all but `#!/bin/bash`, and I still get a timeout. Checking cloudwatch this shows up in the log:

```
/bin/bash: /tmp/OnStart_2020-08-11-07-01jgfhhkwa: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

through testing, I also found that if I add a carriage return before `#!/bin/bash` I get this in the log:

```
/tmp/OnStart_2020-08-11-06-444y3fobzp: line 1: $'\r': command not found
```

based on [this on the \r error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command-not-found-errors-running-bash-scripts-in-wsl), and [this on the ^M error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-script-and-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory), this seems to be an incompatibility between windows and unix formatted text. However, I'm editing the lifecycle configuration through aws on my windows machine:

[image: screenshot of editing the lifecycle config]

is there some way that I can edit this field on my windows machine through AWS, but it be properly written in unix on the other end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, indeed, to do with special character representation in different os' based on [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/issues/8) you can use notepad++ to easily convert the dos representation a unix representation, then just "paste as plain text", and it works fine

- copy to notepad++ view
- show symbol
- show all symbols
- replace "/r" with nothing CRLF should become LF which is valid in unix
- copy and paste as plain text

Doing this fixed the problem