# zsh: command not found: build.sh

Tags: bash, macos, oh-my-zsh

When I try to build my project on the Mac I get the error: `zsh: code not found: build.sh`

I use IntelliJ and Docker.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

[Tried some different things already:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w9CC.jpg)

Comment: You probably don't have `.` on your path, so need to invoke `./build.sh` to get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell doesn't know what is `build.sh`.
Execute this `./build.sh`

If a file is not executable, you need to make it with this command `sudo chmod +x build.sh`

Comment: I ran `sudo chmod +x build.sh`  following `./build.sh`. Got this message: `zsh: ./build.sh: bad interpreter: /bin/bash^M: no such file or directory`

Comment: At first glance, `bad interpreter: /bin/bash^M` - it looks like a new line character problem. 
Take look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-script-and-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

Add permission to execute which you did already with `chmod +x *.sh` (try to avoid that since it gives permission to execute to all scripts, including ones that you don't want to be executable; Instead write specific file name - in your case `chmod +x build.sh`)

You can execute scripts with `./scriptname.sh` for example `./build.sh` - you did it before but without execute rights which now your script has.