# Different env variables for the same NextJS docker image

Tags: docker, environment-variables, next.js13

I'm developing a NextJS 13.5 app for a customer and I'm currently deploying it in a docker container.

Yesterday I received another order for the very same app from another customer, the only different thing in the app is the environment variables. The answer is: Can I Build a docker image with dummy env vars and inject the correct value on runtime (Running with docker run or composing with a .yml)?

Im not sure it is possibile: from the [NextJS official doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20After%20being,or%20during%20initialization)

> Note: After being built, your app will no longer respond to changes to these environment variables. For instance, if you use a Heroku pipeline to promote slugs built in one environment to another environment, or if you build and deploy a single Docker image to multiple environments, all NEXT_PUBLIC_ variables will be frozen with the value evaluated at build time, so these values need to be set appropriately when the project is built. If you need access to runtime environment values, you'll have to setup your own API to provide them to the client (either on demand or during initialization).

Are there any other option to not clone the image and rebuild twice for every update?

I've already tried to simply build and change value by running:
`docker container run -e MYENV="MYVAL"` but is obviously not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, since it's unclear how you intend to use the environment variables. NextJS has two 'parts': code running on the server and code executed in the browser. See [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables) for more details.

**TLDR**;

If you want env to be available in the browser only, you need to use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` variables provided at build time, which for a standard Docker image also means when the image is built. If you intend to use env this way, you *could* do the build at runtime (when running the image), but that would be a hack.

Otherwise you can use env variables at runtime on the server side and deliver those to the browser using `getServerSideProps`, which will built the page at request time.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
Basically I've 2 env vars type:
- 1st type: ONLY server side only (e.g. db key)
- 2nd type: hybrid and needed both in client and server (Like customer ID, customization flatgs, etc..)

I'm currently using the app router, so I tried to "override the db key with

```
 environment:
      - ENV_VAR="B"
```
in docker compose and in run with `docker container run -p 3000:3000 --env-file .\tests\B\.env env-test-a`.

Basically you are telling me I should "Build the nextjs source" in docker run and not in docker build? Did I misunderstood? Thank you so much!

Comment: As mentioned you really shouldn't do that, but if you did it anyway that would work yes. When running the image you can provide `NEXT_PUBLIC_` env variables that will then be available during the build. Notice that this will cause the image to be considerably slower when starting and is not intended behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. The question basically was "Should I ..." and the answer is "no". So imma build different images for different customers.

Thank you again!

Comment: great, then better not do it. Although you could still  use `getServerSideProps`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Default Next.js build only supports environment configuration for running the client browser with the prefix **NEXT_PUBLIC_** at build time. If you still want to read configurations at runtime on the same Docker image, there's a way  to replace build environments variables with custom system environment variables.

### Dockerfile

Sample file `Dockerfile` with mode: **standalone**. Reference: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile

```bash
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/entrypoint.sh ./

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

# Execute script
RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

### entrypoint.sh

Shell script to match and replace config, file sample `entrypoint.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Turn off verbose mode
set +x

# Configuration
envFilename='.env.production'
nextFolder='./.next/'

# # Echo the environment variables
# echo "--- Environment variables ---"
# # Use `env` command to directly output environment variables
# env
# echo "--- Environment variables end ---"
# echo -e "\n"

# Declare an associative array (HashMap)
declare -A configMap

# Function to apply path
apply_path() {
  # local lineNumber=0
  # Read all config file
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    # ((lineNumber++))
    # echo "Line $lineNumber: $line"

    # Ignore comments or empty lines
    if [[ "${line:0:1}" == "#" || -z "$line" || "${line}" =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
      continue
    fi
    
    # Split config name and value
    configName="${line%%=*}"
    configValue="${line#*=}"
    configValue="${configValue%"${configValue##*[![:space:]]}"}"  # Trim trailing whitespace
    configValue="${configValue#\"}"  # Remove leading "
    configValue="${configValue%\"}"  # Remove trailing "

    # Get system env
    envValue=$(env | grep "^$configName=" | cut -d= -f2-)
    envValue="${envValue#\"}"  # Remove leading "
    envValue="${envValue%\"}"  # Remove trailing "

    # Display current line
    echo -e "\e[1;34m=====> Line =====\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[1m$line\e[0m"

    # Display config name
    echo -e "\e[1;34m**** Config Name ****\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[1m$configName\e[0m"

    # Display config value
    echo -e "\e[1;34m**** Config Value ****\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[1m$configValue\e[0m"

    # Display environment value
    echo -e "\e[1;34m**** Environment Value ****\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[1m$envValue\e[0m"

    # If envValue is empty, skip the loop iteration
    if [[ -z "$envValue" ]]; then
      # Push key-value pair into the hashmap
      configMap["$configName"]=$configValue
      continue
    fi

    # Push key-value pair into the hashmap
    configMap["$configName"]=$envValue
    
    # If both config value and env value exist and are not equal
    if [[ -n "$configValue" && -n "$envValue" && "$configValue" != "$envValue" ]]; then
      # Replace config value with env value in files
      echo "Replacing $configValue with $envValue"
      find "$nextFolder" \( -type d -name .git -prune \) -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s#$configValue#$envValue#g"
    fi
    echo -e "\n"
  done < "$envFilename"
}

# Execute function
apply_path

# Starting Nextjs
echo "Starting NextJs NEXT_PUBLIC_REST_API_ENDPOINT: ${configMap['NEXT_PUBLIC_REST_API_ENDPOINT']}"

# Executing additional commands
exec "$@"
```

### Run with other configuration

To run with a different configuration, add the new parameter `--env-file [file_env]` to the docker run command. For example: `--env-file .env.staging`.

```bash
docker run --name [container_name] --env-file [file_env] -d -p [public_port]:[port] [image]:[tag]
#Ex: docker run --name nextjs_1.0_staging --env-file .env.staging -d -p 3001:3000 nextjs:1.0
```

#### Note:

- If you encounter the issue `exec ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory` during Docker build, refer to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-script-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory).
- The provided sample requires the file `.env.production` for the build process.

Comment: this is very different than what i've looked at so far. i think it would be much simpler to maintain 4 different docker files with 4 different environment files. so 12 files if we are including `docker-compose.yml`. 4 `Dockerfile`, 4 `docker-compose.yml` & 4 `.env` for `development`, `testing`, `staging`, & `production`. i'm curious how would your development Dockerfile look like as you don't need `pnpm build` then? i'm on windows & wanna use redis so docker is the only option. [do you know how to do it?](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/62943) new to docker.