# "No such file or directory" when running app on linux arm target

Tags: linux, gcc, intel-fpga

I have a development kit ( Altera Cyclon V, Cortex A9) and I'm trying to run a simple app on it.
I'm using cygwin for cross compiling my code for ARM Linux (using soureforge toolchain for Linux ).

Steps :

1. build within cygwin :  arm-linux-gcc dd.c -s -mcpu=cortex-a9 -s -o ddb
2. copy ddb to target and chmod a+x
3. running it gives me  "./ddb: No such file or directory" . 
   probably a mismatch between lib\tools but I'm new to Linux ( coming from QNX ).

Target is running :

```
   root@socfpga:~/altera# cat /proc/version 
   Linux version 3.9.0 (jdasilva@sj-interactive3) (gcc version 4.7.3 20121106 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.7-2012.1
   1-20121123 - Linaro GCC 2012.11) ) #1 SMP Fri Sep 27 22:55:43 PDT 2013
```

File data of my app :

```
 ddb: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared
 libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.33, stripped
```

File data of a sample hello_world that runs on target :

```
 hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (use
 s shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x2e8fbebd0bdab5897c0c65fb6b
 563f3c34a16eb1, stripped
```

I can see that different DLL are being used ( 2.6.31 vs 2.6.33 ).

How can I solve this?

Comment: ok, fixed it by using Linaro GCC ( which was used to build target )

Answer (score 1):

I've had that problem before when I tried to copy ARM binaries to an ARM android device.

You solved it, but either way, this is what I found out. The problem was the shared libraries. It is trying to load a library that doesn't exist on the target. The "file not found" error is very misleading.

Related question and answers:

["No such file or directory" but it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949161/no-such-file-or-directory-but-it-exists)

Answer (score 0):

could be 64<>32bit problem.
See [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=98129)