# "No such file or directory" but it exists and it's working

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on DBMS project using bash script. I have a problem `No such file or directory` but the file already exists and it's working too but when I source this file from `Main_Menu` file it's not working as expected. Sometimes it's working and sometimes not.

**Drop_DB.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Enter the name of db you want to remove: " db_name

# we use this variable as flag to check everything is ok.
error=""

# function for validations
function validation {
    if [ -d "./DataBases" ]
    then
        error="0"
    else
        error="1"
        echo "Error! DataBases file not exist ❌"
    fi

    if [ -d "./DataBases/$db_name" -a $error = 0 ]
    then
        error="0"
    else
        error="1"
            echo "Error! No Database with this name: $db_name ❌"
    fi
}


# Call function validation first
validation

if [ $error -eq 0 ]
then
        rm -r "./DataBases/$db_name"
    echo "Database: $db_name deleted successfully ✓ ✓"
else

    echo "Can't complete this action ❌"
fi
```

**List_DB.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash


error=""
function validation {
    
    if [ -d "./DataBases" ]
    then
        error="0"
    else
        error="1"
        echo "Error! DataBases file not exist ❌"
    fi


    if [ ! -d "./DataBases/" -a $error = 0 ]
    then
        error="1"
        echo "Error! There's no DBs yet ❌"
    else
        error="0"
    fi
}


# call validation function
validation

if [ $error -eq 0 ]
then
    # 3 - display only directories.
    cd ./DataBases
    ls -d */
else
    echo "Can't complete this action ❌❌"
fi
```

**Main_Menu.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash


options=("Create Database" "List Databases" "Connect To Databases" "Drop Database" "Exit")

PS3="Enter choices from 1 to 5: "
while [[ "$choice" != "Exit" ]]
do
    echo " "
    select choice in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $choice in
            "Create Database" ) source ./Create_DB.sh
                  break
                    ;;
            "List Databases" ) source ./List_DB.sh
                  break
                ;;
            "Connect To Databases" ) source ./Connect_DB.sh
                   break
                ;;
            "Drop Database" ) source ./Drop_DB.sh
                break
                ;;
            "Exit" ) exit
                break
                ;;
            *) echo "Invalid input please try again later"
                    ;;
        esac
    done
done
```

I thought the file needed execute permission but I was wrong:

```
$ ls -l 
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 aem aem  804 Apr  8 14:45 Drop_DB.sh
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 aem aem  696 Apr  8 14:41 Mainmenu.sh
```

Here's the error:

```
./Mainmenu.sh: line25: ./Drop_DB.sh: No such file or directory
```

**Also**, I have tried this: ["No such file or directory" but it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949161/no-such-file-or-directory-but-it-exists) but still have the same error.

**Edit:**

My problem here is that I did `cd` in the `List_DB.sh` file to list all directories there. So, after executing `List_DB.sh`, my `pwd` was `DataBases/$DB_Name` directory and scripts are located in another path which means `No such file or directory` in `DataBases/$DB_Name`. I solved this problem by adding `cd ..` in `List_DB.sh` file to go back to the main folder.

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it covers. The `-a` and `-o` predicates in `test` are marked obsolescent in the POSIX standard document; `[ foo ] && [ bar ]` avoids ambiguities in how `[` parses its arguments and is the current replacement for `[ foo -a bar ]`.

Comment: @AEM you previously mentioned in a (now-deleted) comment that you found and fixed the issue; to help future readers of this Q&A you may want to update the question to include a brief description of the exact issue in your code and how you addressed it; regards

Comment: (well, the "and how you addressed it" part would be better edited into the answer, but with that answer being community-wiki, that's a thing anyone is welcome to do).

Comment: @markp-fuso I don't get it sorry. Should I edit the question and add what helped me to solve the issue or what do you mean?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks a lot for the feedback. I will try to clarify the problem in more details.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I edited the question. Can you please check and tell me what needs to be improved? Thanks a lot for the feedback.

Comment: @AEM the (accepted) answer was more of a 'guess' so I was just suggesting you provide a confirmation on the final resolution and it looks like you've done exactly that with the latest edit of the question; thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple questions/observations:

- the main script calls `List_DB.sh` but this file is not in your `ls -l` output, are your scripts located in different directories?
- since you're sourcing the script files the 'execute' permission is not needed

Keep in mind:

- when a script is exec'd a subshell will be spawned and most operations in the subshell (eg, variable assignments, `cd` operations) are 'lost' when the script exits (in the case of `cd` it's as if the `cd` is 'undone' and you're left back in the directory where you started)
- in the case of a sourced script the commands (in the script) are performed in the current shell so when the script exits any changes made in the shell (variable assignments, `cd` operations) remain in the main shell (in the case of a `cd` you are not returned to where you started)

My guess: the last successfully *sourced* script (`List_DB.sh` ?) performs an operation (eg, `cd`) that leaves the parent script sitting in a different directory hence the error message.